# How to retrieve the headers from a SoapFault

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm using PHP's SoapClient to connect to a webservice (which is out of my control). One of the SoapFaults I'm receiving is as follows (formatted for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <Infolog xmlns="Infolog" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <InfologMessage xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services">
            <InfologMessageType>Error</InfologMessageType>
            <Message>Customer 6729 not found.</Message>
         </InfologMessage>
      </Infolog>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Request Failed. See the Exception Log for details.</faultstring>
         <detail xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <AifFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Fault" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <CustomDetailXml i:nil="true" />
               <FaultMessageListArray i:nil="true" />
               <InfologMessageList xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services" i:nil="true" />
               <StackTrace i:nil="true" />
               <XppExceptionType>3</XppExceptionType>
            </AifFault>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When PHP throws the SoapFault exception, the message is the `Request Failed. See the Exception Log for details.` as would be expected. But what I really need is the `Infolog` entry from the `Header`. Is there any way to retrieve the Header params, other than calling __getLastResponse() and parsing the entire XML myself, which seems very clunky?

I am open to switching client libraries if that will do it - I've so far tried with the native PHP SoapClient and Zend\Soap\Client

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use [__getLastResponseHeaders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php)?

Comment: That returns the HTTP headers from the request. I need the SOAP header, which is in the HTTP body

Comment: Ah, ok. I hate SOAP.  Documentation is lying too, since it says, "Returns the SOAP headers".

Comment: Looooong time ago. Could you get any solution for that?

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho I'm pretty sure I just used the workaround mentioned, and parsed the whole XML from the response